# How to convert String(16) to Int(1) in php

Tags: php

For instance

```
<div ng-repeat = 'list in lists'>

<?php 

 $user_post_id = "{{list.user.id}}";          //this syntax works
 var_dump($user_post_id);                     // gives String(16) '1'     
 $user_post_int_id = (int)$user_post_id;      // change from string to int
 var_dump($user_post_int_id);                 // gives int(1) 0, I don't know why isn't type conversion working!

 echo $user_post_id;                         // echoes out 1
 echo $user_post_int_id;                     //echoes out the 0
```

So the main problem I think is of type conversion, as I tried one more thing where String(1) is converting to int(1) with no problem but with string(16) everything blows apart and results to 0.

Comment: This may help, https://scotch.io/tutorials/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got 3 suggestion 4u (on my server all works fine)

as a original with my comments:

```
<div ng-repeat = 'list in lists'>

<?php 

 $user_post_id = "{{list.user.id}}";          //this syntax works
 var_dump($user_post_id);                     // gives String(16) '1'     
 $user_post_int_id = (int)$user_post_id;      // change to int
 var_dump($user_post_int_id);                 
// gives int(1) 1, is not test your php/server conf!

 echo $user_post_id;                         // echoes out 1
 echo $user_post_int_id;                     //echoes out 1
```

then i advise you to try with your code, run on your server with changes:

1. replace **$user_post_id = "{{list.user.id}}";** 
   to *$user_post_id = (int){{list.user.id}};* 
   //hopes your php wudn't show an error
2. replace **$user_post_int_id = (int)$user_post_id;**
   to *$user_post_int_id = floor((int)$user_post_id);*
   or *$user_post_int_id = ceil((int)$user_post_id);*
3. replace **$user_post_id = "{{list.user.id}}";**
   to *$user_post_id = (int)({{list.user.id}}) + 1 ;*
   or plus zero, these hack sometimes works for me !

p.s.  (int) can do a trick with you, php can thout that you uses hex bin or smth else. retest it twice !
php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php
php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: sorry forget settype() function   see  php.net/manual/ru/function.settype.php

Comment: Hey there Vladmir, But I dropped this approach while dealing with my project, and made it work without mixing JS with php, but thanks for your constructive answer, So I will be accepting it in case anyone else need help for it, and I will be trying to approach this way later in night and let you know,Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Angular expression inside a server side statements, as Angular statement runs on client side after running all server logic.

In your code:

```
<div ng-repeat = 'list in lists'>

<?php 

 $user_post_id = "{{list.user.id}}"          //list.user.id is a JS variable, you cannot use it in PHP.
 $user_post_int_id = (int)$user_post_id;     // something wrong here, you do not need this step, normally if you retrieved the code from server side.

 {{ $user_post_int_id }}                     //this should not work

But still this blade function fails

@if(Auth::user()->id == $user_post_int_id)
do something //returns false, makes alot of sense, as again you are trying to get variables from JS and passing them to PHP scripts. This will never work.
@endif
```

Comment: Hey there @Mina , actually I have changed some of my code, could you please take a look at it again and know what's wrong now?

Comment: hmm, alright, still cheers for helping, I'll ask a new question with further details, But thanks for your time!

Comment: It's not about a new question. It's about understanding how to use back-end scripting and a front-end language. Both live in different spaces, and cannot be mixed.

Comment: But I guess my code is right, and I have found the error as well,
I var_dumped the $user_post_id and it came out to be string(16) "1"
and that's why (int) is not working and resulting to zero , now I need to find a way to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 and then do type conversion.